# Android: disconnect the phone entirely

Tags: android

I'm writing an app to disconnect the phone entirely from the outside. i.e. only local activities are allowed. Things like data, wifi, phone calls, text message are all disabled.

I understand that with MDM one can (probably) change the passcode and lock the phone, which will basically achieve the same thing. But still I'd like to know if one can write such a program on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I assume a possibility would be to put the phone in airplane mode. But sadly this isn't possible anymore, as written in Official Android 4.2 API Documentation.

> Some device settings defined by Settings.System are now read-only. If
>   your app attempts to write changes to settings defined in 
>   Settings.System that have moved to Settings.Global, the write
>   operation will silently fail when running on Android 4.2 and higher.
>   Even if your value for android:targetSdkVersion and 
>   android:minSdkVersion is lower than 17, your app is not able to modify
>   the settings that have moved to Settings.Global when running on
>   Android 4.2 and higher.

I recently tried to implemented something like this, but the only way would be to deactivate everything manually (from what I found)

Comment: thanks. if there is no Java API, is it possible to do this natively and expose some Java APIs?